# NodeJS error with Shopify package instantiating Client

Tags: node.js, npm, shopify

Just need two lines of code importing the Shopify API from NPM and instantiating the client to work without giving errors:

```
import Shopify from '@shopify/shopify-api';

const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest('store_name_here.myshopify.com', 'key_here');
```

Line 2 is throwing the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Rest' of undefined`

Any ideas of what the issue could be? The code is running fine locally but not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use functions from the Shopify-library you need to import it with brackets, `{Shopify}`.

So your import would look like this instead:

```
import {Shopify} from '@shopify/shopify-api';
```